# Comparing goodness of least-squares fits through origin

Tags: regression, least-squares

I was wondering how to measure the goodness of fit of a linear least squares regression constrained through the origin. I have been using r-squared for comparing unconstrained fits, but I understand that this is less useful when the fit is constrained.

Comment: mean square error?